# jquery how to execute ajax on load of page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to make an ajax call every x seconds. What I would also like to know is how can i register the same ajax function to execute on page load?

Here is what my ajax function looks like (fires every 30 seconds)...

```
$().ready(function() {

    // Poll for bulletin bar message
    var url = $.url("/pollBulletin.htm");
    pollTimer = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(data) {
                // The server may be down for the night or there may be a 
                // network blip. As such try to poll 10 times
                // if still failing kill the poll.
                retryCount = retryCount + 1;
                if (pollTimer != null && retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                    clearInterval(pollTimer);
                }
            },
            success: function(bulletinBarMessage) {
                // Once we have a successful poll reset the retry count.
                retryCount = 0;
                var respContent = "";
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.messageLevel + " : ";  
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.message;  
                $("#mt-news").html('<ul><a href="#" target="_self">' + respContent + '</a></ul>');
            }
        });
        // When communication with the server is lost stop the poll.
        }, pollInterval);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: @Satpal ya it should be even wrong syntax used by OP will work too, because of ready promise used internally by jQuery

Comment: When it comes to make ajax requests on interval delay, don't use an interval, consider to use a timeout instead and recall a new one only once request has been completed. Even here, 30secs should be enough to let previous request to complete, but who knows what can happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same function on page load as you do in setInterval().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Poll for bulletin bar message
var url = $.url("/pollBulletin.htm");

loadData();
pollTimer = setInterval(loadData, pollInterval);

function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(data) {
            // The server may be down for the night or there may be a 
            // network blip. As such try to poll 10 times
            // if still failing kill the poll.
            retryCount = retryCount + 1;
            if (pollTimer != null && retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                clearInterval(pollTimer);
            }
        },
        success: function(bulletinBarMessage) {
            // Once we have a successful poll reset the retry count.
            retryCount = 0;
            var respContent = "";
            respContent += bulletinBarMessage.messageLevel + " : ";  
            respContent += bulletinBarMessage.message;  
            $("#mt-news").html('<ul><a href="#" target="_self">' + respContent + '</a></ul>');
        }
    });
}
});
```

As [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) suggested you should also introduce a timeout.

Comment: It should be: `pollTimer = setInterval(loadData, pollInterval);`

Answer (score 0):

you should put your code in document.ready as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Poll for bulletin bar message
    var url = $.url("/pollBulletin.htm");
    pollTimer = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(data) {
                // The server may be down for the night or there may be a 
                // network blip. As such try to poll 10 times
                // if still failing kill the poll.
                retryCount = retryCount + 1;
                if (pollTimer != null && retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                    clearInterval(pollTimer);
                }
            },
            success: function(bulletinBarMessage) {
                // Once we have a successful poll reset the retry count.
                retryCount = 0;
                var respContent = "";
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.messageLevel + " : ";  
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.message;  
                $("#mt-news").html('<ul><a href="#" target="_self">' + respContent + '</a></ul>');
            }
        });
        // When communication with the server is lost stop the poll.
        }, pollInterval);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    makeAjaxCall();

    setInterval(function() {
          // Do something every 30 seconds
          makeAjaxCall();
    }, 30000);

    function makeAjaxCall() {
      // your ajax call from here
    }
});
```

Incase you need to implement what [A Wollf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660114/jquery-how-to-execute-ajax-on-load-of-page/22660187#comment34515787_22660114) has said, heres how it should be done,

> > When it comes to make ajax requests on interval delay, don't use an interval, consider to use a timeout instead and recall a new one only once request has been completed

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    makeAjaxCall();

    function makeAjaxCall() {
      // your ajax call from here
      $.ajax({
        // option1
        // option2
        // option3
        success: function(){setTimeout(makeAjaxCall, 30)},
        error: function(){setTimeout(makeAjaxCall, 30)},
      })
    }
});
```